# Can't receive MMS on Aquaris-E4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bug-reporting, mms

I experience a bug with my brand new aquaris e4'5 Ubuntu Touch edition:
I can send MMS but can't receive.

Other French people seems to experience it too, with another provider (I'm on free mobile, other are using orange or sosh) and same phone specifications.

My data connection is working great, sms too. Modify parameters seems have no effect.

If this bug is confirmed, where can i report it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be hitting this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nuntium/+bug/1417976

There are some questions being asked in that bug that perhaps you can provide answers for to help us debug.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it'sounds like! I'll collect logs & update this bug. Thanks a lot