# meizu pro 5, ota-14, still no working mms

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mms

I have updated my meizu pro 5 to ota-14 recently and still it's not possible to either receive or send mms.

I know that a bug existed in ota-4, so maybe it's fixed. Some files are missing in my phone.

Does anyone have any good suggestion or knowledge about this problem?

Comment: do you have mobile data on?

Comment: It appears that this user has a similar issue to yours. I would also check that you have data on (http://askubuntu.com/questions/602113/cant-receive-mms-on-aquaris-e4-5)

Comment: yes, the data is on all the time